# Android fixed-speed LayoutTransition

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-transitions

I've figured out how to enable layout transitions using [`LayoutTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) (see also [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)), and have managed to customise the timing and duration of the transitions using [`setStartDelay()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html#setStartDelay(int,%20long)) and [`setDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html#setDuration(int,%20long)).

I'm using this to animate showing and hiding sections in my app's settings page, and it's looking pretty good.

However, while `setDuration()` does have an effect on the transition speed (e.g. the speed at which a view sliding up to close the gap left by a hidden view above), the speed is not constant because some views are taller than others... with a fixed duration you'll get different sliding speeds.

Is there a way to set the transition *speed* rather than *duration*?  Perhaps I need to use a different method of animating the layout (e.g. [this](https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/android-tips-expandablecollapsible-views/)), but I'm attracted to the method I'm already using because it has the benefit of simplicity... and my app has a minimum API of 16 so this may rule out some more recent methods.

Comment: so you need to find out how the distance and the duration relate to the speed